# 500 (Internal Server Error) on YII2 when reading post data

Tags: php, yii2

I want to insert a data to a table with post request using ajax, but i cant read the data that i just send with ajax, heres my code :

Ajax code :

```
$('#newList').on('beforeSubmit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#newList").modal('hide');
$("#title").val("");
load(1);
$.ajax({
    url: '/site/add-list',
    type: 'post',
    data: {title : $("#title").val()},
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); // return 500 (Internal Server Error)
    }
});
```

});

Controller :

```
public function actionAddList()
{
    $req = Yii::$app->request;
    $newList = new Boards();
    return $req->post(); // return 500 (Internal Server Error)

}
```

everytime i send a post request it keeps saying 500 (Internal Server Error) on console. But when i return a string for ex. "asdasd" it works. How do i fix this ?

Comment: Please look into the Webservers error log. It will show you the full error text, not only Error 500.  Then post the relevant error here.

Comment: Where are you accessing the post data? I miss something like $name = $request->post('title')  https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-requests

Comment: As Alexander mentioned, you're shooting in the dark - you must look for the logs in order to identify the specific error. 500 error means something on the server's side is wrong. In the weblog you'd see exactly what's wrong - which file, which line.  Until you'd share the logs with us - try to comment the line: "    $newList = new Boards();". Does it work now?

Comment: If you use Mozilla debugger, in Network tab where is your request you can see the request response. Also what is your purpose? You send some string with post and after that you return it the same?

Comment: @vvpanchev my aim is to insert the string into a table and display it on flash message

Comment: @MelvinJovano Did you see what's your error message?

Comment: You're trying to return an array when it expects a `string` or `Response` by default. Use `return $this->asJson($req);`

Comment: @vvpanchev no i didnt and

Comment: @Alex yup, youre right thats the main problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for late response, so the problem is in my controller, it should be looking like this so that the ajax can read the value im returning

```
public function actionAddList()
{
    $req = Yii::$app->request;

    if ($req->isAjax) {
        $res = ['data' => $req->post()];
        $newList = new Lists();
        $newList->title = $res["data"]["title"];
        $newList->save();
        echo $res["data"]["title"]; // Isnt error anymore
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

I got the error because i returning an array on my controller, so i just have to do something like this

```
    // Bad
    return array(
        "data" => 'blabla'
    );

    // Good
    $dat = array(
        "data" => "blabla"
    );
    return $dat["data"];
```

The reason i got 500 Error from console is probably comes from YII because the response content must not be an array.

```
if (is_array($this->content)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Response content must not be an array.');
    } elseif (is_object($this->content)) {
        if (method_exists($this->content, '__toString')) {
            $this->content = $this->content->__toString();
        } else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Response content must be a string or an object implementing __toString().');
        }
    }
```